# Looking for good approach for two levels of authentication in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I need two levels of authentication in a Rails app using the same username. One to login and a second to view more sensitive areas such as billing and credit card info. The first level is implemented with Devise. For second level can I use Devise again a different model like setting? Cancan require separate logins.

Not sure of the best approach.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: I think second part is related to authorization you can use cancan as per my guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is so unconventional that it seems there can not be used a ready solution. In my opinion, dual authorization is not necessary in this case (the second password is usually used to confirm some action, not for a second authorization), but sometimes we do not choose such things.

Dirty solution would be to hold another encrypted password, and when you enter to second level give the user a different role temporarily. This role will be checked at the cancan. The role  resets during for a  while or at the next login (so that an attacker have not at the same time access to billing). I think it's very rough, but a quick solution.

This is just my 50 cents, I doubt that this is a good solution.